# Insert a Line Break after text in TextBox ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I need to add line break after the following in the textbox.

```
txtBody.Value = "Dear " & Trim(tblProperty(0).Item("Contact")) & ","
```

I've tried so far 'ControlChars.CrLf', ..., 'vbNewLine', 'vbCrLf', ... at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 1):

Set textbox property `TextMode="MultiLine"`.

Then try this for example:

`txtBody.Value = "Dear " & "\n" & "Dear".`

Comment: This displayed as \n .... Environment.NewLine did the trick in vb, thanks for your help.